# ASP.NET Windows Authentication - Page cannot be displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, iis-8

I have created a simple WebForm asp.net web site. I have disabled the Windows Authentication checks within the code but set IIS8 to "Windows Authentication" as well as the web.config. I perform the `Indentity.IsAuthenticated` check in the backend to ensure the user is authenticated.

My issue is I get "The page cannot be displayed, please check your URL is correct". (This is in IE)

If I set my authentication to Anonymous the site works fine. I disable Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication only and receive this error. I have done quite abit of reading now and think I am just missing something small.
I used the IIS "default site" and set it to Windows Authentication and got a login prompt (as expected).

The server is running IIS8, windows 2012. Windows Authentication is installed as a feature, IIS site settings is set to use Windows Authentication only, as is the web.config. The web.config doesn't have Authorization tags for deny and allow but has `<authentication mode="Windows" />`. The errors occur on both IE and FireFox. No windows events are logged so i assume it's purely a authentication error that isn't displaying the site. The AppPool is set to `Identity`.

I think what confuses me most is the "default site" (with no code or logic) works and my site doesn't. The default site also doesn't have a web.config.

Any ideas would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may have to do with Kereberos.

I had the same issue and whilst troubleshooting server side issues, my co worker indicated that he was able to access the site.

It was then I realized my issue was a client side issue.  Something may have been wrong with my Kerberos tickets.  Maybe the domain controller that initially issued the ticket to me went offline.  Rebooting my workstation was what got windows authentication working for me again.

Some other things you can try are:
Try changing your windows authentication provider to NTLM as a test.
Click on the site -> Click Authentication  -> Click Windows Authentication -> Click Providers
Move NTLM to the top or add it if it isn't there.
Click ok.
IISReset.  And try again.

If you prefer to use Kerberos, you may have to set the service principal names using the setspn.exe command.

For more information on Kerberos
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2014/04/17/setting-up-kerberos-authentication-for-a-website-in-iis/

Other things to check:
- Check your authorization rules and .NET Authorization Rules to ensure All Users are allowed to access the site.

- Look in your IIS logs located at C:\inetpub\logs for more clues.  In the folder, you'll find a folder for each site named after the site's id.  You can find the site id clicking Sites on the IIS Management console.  The site ids of each site will be displayed there.
- Verify the application pool identity of the site has enough permissions.